# Unexpected result loading partial view into an IE8 DOM using jQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a strange result happening when loading a Partial View using jQuery Ajax into the DOM, but only when viewing the result using IE8.

The Partial View in question (for example purposes only) looks like this;

```
<aside>Example test</aside>
```

When the result comes back from the Ajax call it appears to look exactly as above. However when viewing the DOM using the developer tools in IE8 the result looks like this;

```
<aisde/>
Example test
</aside/>
```

As a result the element is not recognised and the text does not sit within it. Also the style sheet class for 'aside' is not being applied. This only happens in IE8 as far as I can see.

Any one got any suggestions, other than do not use custom tags?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What document mode is the page running?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the DOM recognizes HTML5 elements. Essentially you will have to do:

```
document.createElement('aisde');
```

Have a look at [this](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/) link. Without creating the element older IE browsers will not see or style the elements.

The common practice around these issues is to load a [html5 fix javascript](http://remysharp.com/downloads/html5.js) file within a conditional comment block. The script does a `createElement` on all new html5 node types.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately this is coming from a partial view so am unable to perform a document.createElement. Do you know of any other way of forcing a browser to render the tag correctly. 

In addition, if I perform a $("#container").html("<aside>Test</aside>"); it renders correctly with css styling as well.

Comment: @davidferguson - See my update. This should go into the master page (layout page) not in the partial.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I have tried implementing this with no luck. I tried putting the <aside> tag in the DOM without loading from a partial and it worked fine in IE8. So it appears to only be a problem when loading from a Partial View. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @davidferguson - make sure you have a valid HTML5 doctype, and are you sure that the page you are loading the partial view, has previously loaded the `html5.js` file?

Comment: I have just checked the doctype and it is a valid html5 doctype. I am loading the js file in my _site.cshtml layout which the parent page inherits from, so should be loaded when the partial view is loaded in.